# Merge pandas dataframes with multiindex columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge two dataframes in `pandas` that both have multi-index columns. The merge should be an outer merge on a column that is present in both dataframes. See minimal example and resulting error below:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrames with multi-index columns
data1 = {
    ('A', 'X'): [1, 2, 3],
    ('A', 'Y'): [4, 5, 6],
    ('B', 'X'): [7, 8, 9],
    ('B', 'Y'): [10, 11, 12],
}

data2 = {
    ('A', 'X'): [13, 14, 15],
    ('A', 'Y'): [16, 17, 18],
    ('B', 'X'): [19, 20, 21],
    ('B', 'Y'): [22, 23, 24],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])

# Merge on a specific column (e.g., ('A', 'X'))
column_to_merge_on = ('A', 'X')
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=column_to_merge_on, right_on=column_to_merge_on)

print(merged_df)
```

Resulting error:

```py
ValueError: The column label 'A' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working add list like `[('A', 'X')]`:

```
#changed data for match
data1 = {
    ('A', 'X'): [1, 2, 13],
    ('A', 'Y'): [4, 5, 6],
    ('B', 'X'): [7, 8, 9],
    ('B', 'Y'): [10, 11, 12],
}

data2 = {
    ('A', 'X'): [13, 14, 15],
    ('A', 'Y'): [16, 17, 18],
    ('B', 'X'): [19, 20, 21],
    ('B', 'Y'): [22, 23, 24],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])


# Merge on a specific column (e.g., ('A', 'X'))
column_to_merge_on = [('A', 'X')]
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, 
                     left_on=column_to_merge_on, 
                     right_on=column_to_merge_on, how='outer')
```

---

```
print(merged_df)
    A   A_x       B_x         A_y   B_y      
    X     X    Y    X     Y     Y     X     Y
0   1   1.0  4.0  7.0  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   2   2.0  5.0  8.0  11.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  13  13.0  6.0  9.0  12.0  16.0  19.0  22.0
3  14   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  17.0  20.0  23.0
4  15   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  18.0  21.0  24.0
```

Comment: That works, cheers! For me it was rather confusing the error message kept asking for a `tuple`.